# Allow access to component file or install in root

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

i am developing Joomla 2.5 component and i run into some problems:

It seems that in htaccess file is set to forbid access to php files inside /components folder. But my component needs to have one file that will be accessed from external application (that file will receive requests from external servers/domains).

One solution is to somehow change htaccess during installation of component, but i think it is stupid and unsecure thing to do.

Other idea is to place that file to root folder of site, but how to make installation to do this (maybe to change/add something in main xml file or.....)?

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. How will the external apps access the file `curl` some other mechanism...   2. Do you have control over the URL the external apps will use to access the php file?

Comment: 1. External app will access it by sending simple php GET request with multiple parameters, and it will expect response (i only need to echo that response). 2. Yes, i have control, i can change that URL.

Comment: Then you can just have the external app access the component directly and pass it to a controller that only returns the data you want e.g. raw, JSON, XML etc...

Answer (score 0):

In the file you want to access, trying replacing this:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

with the following:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
```

else remove the line of code fully, however I should warn you that this does pose a security threat.